# How can i include JWT in Silex with SecurityProvider

Tags: jwt, silex

I create app with Silex. I'm using for user authentication the "SecurityServiceProvider". The users are stored in the database. My firewall configuration look like:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'secure_area_edison' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/admin/',
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
                'users' => function () use ($app) {
                    return new App\Services\UserProvider($app['db']);
                },
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Now i want to create a API for my app. The api will return JSON Responses. All functions from the API can be accessed through the uri "/api/".

I found some topics in case of JWT and try to include JWT in my App. But i'm not sure how can include JWT in my app or it's possible to combine the classic authentication with JWT in Silex?

Have someone a example or hint for me?